# How to execute (using bash) a buffer with line continuations (\)?

Tags: terminal, terminal-buffer

In vim8, you can do:

```
:. term
```

to send the current line to execute in your terminal's shell (e.g., bash).

But how, in normal and ex mode, do you execute a single line that contains line continuations -- ie backslash characters (`\`) like the following?

```
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/films/select?q=*:*&rows=0'\
'&facet=true'\
'&facet.range=initial_release_date'\
'&facet.range.start=NOW-20YEAR'\
'&facet.range.end=NOW'\
'&facet.range.gap=%2B1YEAR'
```

The following works but seems clumsy:

```
:%s/\\\n// | . term
```

Comment: just select the lines in visual mode, then `:'<,'>term` or use any other range

Comment: @Mass that works great "as is" (thanks!), but fails if I use tabs or spaces on subsequent lines: `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: &facet=true` and `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: &facet.range=initial_release_date` etc

Comment: are you sure that even works in bash?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/7316194